# Add http:// to an url that have double slash at the beginning (or nothing)

Tags: php, url

For instance, I need to add **http://** to submitted url like :

> //www.mydomain.com/images/icon-32.png (double slash at the beginning)

or

> www.mydomain.com/images/icon-32.png

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine for your problem.

```
$url = "//mydomain.com/images/icon-32.png";
// or $url = "mydomain.com/images/icon-32.png";
// Checking if string starts with '//'
if(strpos($url, "//")===0){
    $url = "http:" . $url;
}else{
    // Checking if string doesn't already start with 'http://'
    if(!strpos($url, "http://")===0 || strpos($url, "http://")===false)
        $url = "http://" . $url;
}
echo $url;
```